# std::string assignment through index doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, string, indexing, stdstring

in c++

when I declare

```
string string1;
```

then I'm not able to assign by index as in

```
string1[0] = 'x';
```

however if I first put string1 = "somestring"; then I am able to use the assignment through index.

```
string = "";
```

doesnt work

so I'm wondering why is this. I thought std::string was supposed to have index functionality.

Answer (score 2):

When you default construct a string, it's empty. There are no elements its char array, so `[0]` doesn't exist. If you construct it by giving it a string, like `"somestring"`, it contains that string and the zeroth index is `s`.

Comment: how would one construct a string to be ready to be indexed? string string1[0] ?

Comment: @user3713215, It sounds like you should get a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

When you have `string string1;` you are declaring an empty string.  You have to assign a value to it before you can access a character of the string through an index.

It won't create index 0 of an empty string for you just by `string1[0] = 'x';`  It will, however allow you to change the value at index 0 if there are characters already there in the string.

You can create a 'preallocated' string of sorts through the constructor:
`string (size_t n, char c);` where `n` is  the number of characters to copy and `c` is the character to fill the string with.  So, for example, you could have `std::string string1(5, ' ');` which would create a string filled with 5 spaces. You could then use any index from 0-4 in order to put other values in the string (as in your original question - `string1[0] = 'x';`).  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/